# Is there any way to remove duplicates in python based on two conditions?

Tags: python, dataframe, duplicates, boolean

I am trying to remove duplicates based on two conditions but I have not been able to.

My code is this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'State': ['NY', 'NY', 'FL', 'AL', 'NY', 'TX', 'FL', 'AL'],
                   'Quantity': [120, 162, 120, 120, 120, 72, 120, 81],
                   'Duplicate': ['TRUE', 'FALSE', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 'TRUE', 'FALSE'],
                   'YN': ['FALSE', 'FALSE', 'TRUE', 'TRUE', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 'TRUE', 'FALSE'],},
                  index=['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'One', 'Two', 'Three', 'One', 'Two'])

print("\n -------- Duplicate Rows ----------- \n")
print(df)

df1 = df.reset_index().drop_duplicates(subset=['Duplicate','YN'],
                                       keep='first').set_index('index')

print("\n ------- Unique Rows ------------ \n")
print(df1)
```

And the outcome is:

```
index                                 
One      NY       120      TRUE  FALSE
Two      NY       162     FALSE  FALSE
Three    FL       120      TRUE   TRUE
One      AL       120     FALSE   TRUE
```

However, I want to remove the columns where Duplicate and YN are TRUE.

I have tried several things but when I try to run this:

```
df1 = df.reset_index().drop_duplicates(subset=['Duplicate' == 'TRUE' & 'YN' == 'TRUE],
                                       keep='first').set_index('index')
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'str'
```

I cannot find if my error is because the columns are boolean and I will need to add a third column later where I would have to remove if the three are TRUE

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hint: `'Duplicate' == 'TRUE' & 'YN' == 'TRUE'` is the same as `'Duplicate' == ('TRUE' & 'YN') == 'TRUE'`. Also, what do you expect this expression to evaluate to?

Comment: What is the point of using the strings `"True"` and `"False"` instead of actual boolean values? _I cannot find if my error is because the columns are boolean_ They aren't bools, and even if they were, the error message doesn't say anything about bools.

Comment: I am trying to remove all rows where both columns are TRUE and they come from a previous script where they were evaluated as boolean and the result was this (some lines ended up being TRUE and some others are FALSE). Should I convert them to text first? Or what do you  suggest?

Answer (score 0):

You can select the subset of entries where both Duplicate and  YN are true using the following:

```
df1 = df.loc[(df['Duplicate'] == True) & (df['YN'] == True)]
```

Comment: For some reason when I replace this line into the script I get an empty data frame.

Answer (score 0):

Python interpreter read it like this:

`'TRUE' & 'YN'`. As if you were trying "logical and" operation between 2 string .

I believe you might need to replace `&` with `and`